# django pre-calculate and cache a view

Tags: python, django

This might be a python question. It is a noobish one to be sure.

A client requests a calculation-intensive page [page-1] and will ultimately request a second calculation-intensive page [page-2], which can be calculated the instance the request for page-1 is known. I don't want to calculate each set of data before serving page-1 because it will significantly slow down the performance of the initial response.

I do want to calculate the value for page-2 while the client reads page-1. The client also might click on some buttons which cause a response that provides a different view of page-1 data, but don't necessitate an intensive calculating. Eventually but not necessarily immediately, the client will ask for page-2 and I want to be able to response with a pre-rendered response.

How do I do this?

Comment: You'd want to trigger an asynchronous function that calculates page 2 based on page1 information, store it in a cache (or anywhere), then in page 2: continually poll a view which knows to check for a certain key in cache so as to determine when the background task finished calculating the step2 task.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. Any little guidance would help a lot.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't go into much more detail without writing an essay. Basically, you need to trigger this expensive function as soon as client1 read the page. If you don't want the client to wait for it before loading the page, you need to make the job asynchronous. A background task. Then, in page2, you need to account for the possibility that the background job is NOT complete yet. Thus, your second page needs to have a mechanism to continually poll the server until the BG task is complete, at which point you can show page2 to your user.

Comment: Actually, a simpler implementation for page 2 is to simply ask the user to refresh the page until the job is complete? Anyways, this is a comment and not an answer for a reason. I hope somebody is able to answer your question. I'm just trying to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it sounds like you're going to need to handle this with an asynchronous background task, saving the result in the [Django low level cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#the-low-level-cache-api). I would personally use [celery](http://celeryproject.org) for the task queue.

Basically, after page one is requested, you would add an asynchronous task to start the page 2 calculations, storing the result in the cache. So, when page 2 is requested, you check for the pre-rendered response in the cache, and if it doesn't exist, you could calculate the value synchronously.

So, your code would look something like this (the task would be in a task.py file in your app, but this should give you a general idea):

```
from celery import task
from django.core.cache import cache

def page_two_calculation(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2

@task
def page_two_task(arg1, arg2):
    result = page_two_calculation(arg1, arg2)
    cache_key = "page-two-%s-%s" (arg1, arg2)
    cache.set(cache_key, result)

def page_one(request, arg1, arg2):

    # Start the page two task
    page_two_task.delay(arg1, arg2)

    # Return the page one response
    return HttpResponse('page one')

def page_two(request, arg1, arg2)
    cache_key = "page-two-%s-%s" (arg1, arg2)
    result = cache.get(cache_key)
    if result is None:
         # the result will only be None if the page 2 calculation
         # doesn't exist in the cache, in which case we'll have to
         # return the value synchronously.
         result = page_two_calculation(arg1, arg2)
    return result
```